Cloud Build trigger error with roles/run.admin, roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
I have a problem with my Google Cloud project, when I want to deploy the project (web api net core) I get role errors: required oles: roles/run.admin, roles/iam.serviceAccountUser.
I tried to activate them but no matter what I try, the same error comes out:
run.admin:

ServiceAccountUser:

img error trigger:
permissions



The error clearly says it needs permissions for the Cloud Build account, not your accounts

I tried it, but the same error continues, did I do it correctly? I updated the body question

Is that the Service Account used by Cloud Build? If you're using the default one it finishes in @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com This is well documented so read the docs first https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-access-for-cloud-build-service-account#service-account-permissions-iam-page

yes, endswith @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Can you show an screenshot of that account with the permissions?

i uploaded the screenshot

Can you enable the: Set as preferred service account and try again?

the same error, i'll try with other account

If you list the roles of the cloudbuild SA does it has the roles that are mentioned in the error?

run.admin is id ID of Rules/Cloud run. and serviceAccountUser is in IAM configurations , i think
